# Elasticsearch from filtered documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have configured one index which is indexed on all the documents.

Now sometimes I have another filters, which narrows down my search criteria.

So now I have very limited documents to search.

So is there a way to define those documents to elastic search, so that it doesnot return all the documents but from those filtered documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. They have filter given for this.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [ "1", "2" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html